# Windows 7 and setting Scarlett 18i20 sync source

Tags: sync, audio-interfaces, sample-rate, clock

Just installed an RME Hammerfall 9652 this weekend which is the primary soundcard for Ableton Live. I use a Focusrite Scarlett 18i20 to input all my analog gear into, to pass on to the RME. I successfully got all the audio routed, but I am stuck on clocking the 18i20 from the RME.

The RME is set to internal clock, and I pass clock data over ADAT to the 18i20. It seems to work just fine at 44.1 kHz sample rate, but if I set the RME clock to 48 kHz, the 18i20's sync status unlocks and never changes to correspond to the RME.

Has anyone else experienced this on Windows 7? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: I'm confused about why you are routing audio from one interface to another interface instead of routing it into the application(s) you are using. And I'm assuming the 18i20 is configured to get its clock from its ADAT input? After changing the rate on the RME, have you tried power cycling the 18i20 and/or changing the 18i20 clock source to internal and then back to ADAT? I seem to recall having to do something like that with my 18i6.

Comment: If you look at the RME there is no way to interface TRS audio cables into it. The RME is far superior as a primary interface, and I need something that will take TRS/XLR from my synths, therefore the 18i20. Either way it's not the issue. The issue is the 18i20 can only lock from external clocks on 44.1 kHz. As my DAW is using the RME as primary audio device, I would like to make sure that the sample rate can match RME's at 48 kHz. No matter what I do, the sync status will not leave 44.1 kHz on the 18i20. Even if I manually change it. Strange. I have not tried your suggestion yet.